# In Single Sign On what does SAML "enabled" control do or mean?

Tags: security, signup-signon, authentication

I am currently working on the redesign of SSO signup process/form and want to understand what enabling SAML control implies.

The rationale being that if an organisation does not have SSO enabled the user will be prompted to signup by imputing required details and following the process through rather than enabling first and then inputting the details. Am I missing something here? Is this a backend requirement?

Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Note: I understand what SAML is, just don't understand why there is a UI control/switch for it (TickBox). Is this not adding an unnecessary step to the workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know what [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) is, I'm not going to go into specifics of that and simply consider it a system for federated sign-ups / log-ins.

What you've shows seems to be a simple option as to **whether the application should use a federated sign-on or not**.  Some organisations prefer to have all the login and security information for a user stored locally, and in those situations they wouldn't enable federated sign-ups.

Take this site for example.  When you sign-up for an account you have three options.  Two are federated sign-ups, and one is internal.

[image]

If you were to have a setup for some software like this site, and you chose not to use a federated sign-up, you would end up with only the one option, and the sign-up would look like this:

[image]